# IBM HTTP Server v8.5 installed with warnings. Not able to start the apachectl.

Tags: apache, webserver, ibmhttpserver

I installed the IBM  HTTP Server v8.5 on RHEL machine . Installation completed with some warnings and some logs in postinstall directory. when I tried to start the Server with the command ./apachectl start i got the error message :"IBM/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory" Pleae guide in solving this issue.

Please find the log in postinstall directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876463</millis>
<sequence>4</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.Launcher</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.Launcher</class>
<method>fillInCommandLineArguments</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Incoming arguments are: -WS_CMT_ACTION_REGISTRY, 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/deltaActionRegistry.xml, -
WS_CMT_EXTENSION, com.ibm.ws.postinstall.cmext.ConfigManagerExtension, -
WS_PI_ACTION_REGISTRY_EXTENSION, 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/registryExtension.xml, -
actionTarget, install, -WS_CMT_CONF_DIR, 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/, -permissionsProcessing, false, 
-CREATE_ADMIN_AUTH, false, -CREATE_IHS_SERVICE, false, -WS_CMT_HIDE_KEYS, 
ADMIN_AUTH_PASSWORD, -ADMIN_SERVICE_NAME, "", -SERVER_NAME, , -ADMUSER, , -
RUN_SETUPADM, false, -WEBSERVER_DEFINITION, , -ADMIN_PORT, , -HTTP_PORT, 
8080, -ADMIN_AUTH_PASSWORD, ********, -IHS_HOME, /app/IBM/HTTPServer, -
ADMGRP, , -ADMIN_AUTH_USER, , -IHS_SERVICE_NAME, "none", -JAVA_DIR, 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer/java/jre, -CREATE_ADMIN_SERVICE, false, -SERVER_ROOT, 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer, -CREATE_ADMUSER, false</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876469</millis>
<sequence>5</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.PlatformConstants</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.PlatformConstants</class>
<method>getCurrentPlatform</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Current platform was detected as Linux</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876470</millis>
<sequence>6</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</class>
<method>getEnvironmentVariableValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Value of WS_CMT_EXTRINSICS could not be extracted from the process 
environment, returning null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876470</millis>
<sequence>7</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</logger>
<level>INFO</level>

<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</class>
<method>getArgumentValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Could not resolve this argument: WS_CMT_EXTRINSICS, returning 
null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876471</millis>
<sequence>8</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</class>
<method>getEnvironmentVariableValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Value of WS_CMT_EXTENSION_LIB could not be extracted from the 
process environment, returning null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876471</millis>
<sequence>9</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
 </class>
<method>getArgumentValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Could not resolve this argument: WS_CMT_EXTENSION_LIB, returning 
null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876517</millis>
<sequence>10</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</class>
<method>getEnvironmentVariableValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Value of omitAction could not be extracted from the process 
environment, returning null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876517</millis>
<sequence>11</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</class>
<method>getArgumentValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Could not resolve this argument: omitAction, returning 
null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876517</millis>
<sequence>12</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</class>
<method>getEnvironmentVariableValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Value of omitAction1 could not be extracted from the process 
environment, returning null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876517</millis>
<sequence>13</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</class>
<method>getArgumentValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Could not resolve this argument: omitAction1, returning 
null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876517</millis>
<sequence>14</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</class>
<method>getEnvironmentVariableValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Value of PRE_IJC_LIB could not be extracted from the process 
environment, returning null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876517</millis>
<sequence>15</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher.ArgumentValueFetcher 
</class>
<method>getArgumentValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Could not resolve this argument: PRE_IJC_LIB, returning 
null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876519</millis>
<sequence>16</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.utils.FileUtils</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.utils.FileUtils</class>
<method>getAllFilesInThisDirectory</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/lib is not a directory, 
 returning an empty list</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876519</millis>
<sequence>17</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.utils.FileUtils</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.utils.FileUtils</class>
<method>getAllFilesInThisDirectoryMatchingThisPatternIgnoreCase</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>List of files in /app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/lib 
matching the pattern ^.*\.jar$ is: {  }</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876520</millis>
<sequence>18</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.utils.ClassPathModifier</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.utils.ClassPathModifier</class>
<method>addAllJARsInDirectoryToClassPath</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>ListJAR files in found in 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/lib is: {  }</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876520</millis>
<sequence>19</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment</class>
<method>getEnvironmentVariableValue</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Value of POST_IJC_LIB could not be extracted from the process 
 environment, returning null</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:56</date>
<millis>1491890876520</millis>
<sequence>20</sequence>

<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877013</millis>
<sequence>80</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmt 
LogAdapter </logger>
<level>WARNING</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.logging.LogUtils</class>
<method>logException</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/actions/ 
CallPostinst.ant:163: The ServerName property must be non-empty
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Exit.execute(Exit.java:139)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets 
(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils. 
InProcessAntRunner.runBuild (InProcessAntRunner.java:801)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils. 
InProcessAntRunner.start(InProcessAntRunner.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine. 
ANTAction.executeActionUsingAnInProcessANTCall(ANTAction.java:120)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine. 
ANTAction.executeAction(ANTAction.java:54)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine 
.ConfigAction.executeAction(ConfigAction.java:95)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager. 
executeAllActionsFound(ConfigManager.java:1125)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager. 
executeActions(ConfigManager.java:620)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager. 
ConfigManager.launch(ConfigManager.java:380)
at com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.launcher. 
Launcher.mainForInProcessCMTCallersWithContextSwitch(Launcher.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.postinstall.LaunchConfigManager. 
runUsingAPI(LaunchConfigManager.java:26)
at com.ibm.ws.postinstall.LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller. 
launchConfigManagerWithRegistry(LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller.java:471)
at com.ibm.ws.postinstall.LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller. 
launchConfigManager(LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller.java:348)
at com.ibm.ws.postinstall.LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller. 
runPostinstaller(LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller.java:244)
at com.ibm.ws.postinstall.LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller.main 
(LaunchUnifiedPostInstaller.java:77)
</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877013</millis>
<sequence>81</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils. 
ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant. 
utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
<method>buildFinished</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Build stopped - FAILURE</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877014</millis>
<sequence>82</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ANTAction</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ANTAction</class>
<method>executeAction</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Result of executing 
/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/actions/CallPostinst.ant was: 
false</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877014</millis>
<sequence>83</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</logger>
<level>WARNING</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</class>
<method>executeAllActionsFound</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Configuration action failed: 
com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ConfigAction- 
 /app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/actions /CallPostinst.ant 
</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877014</millis>
<sequence>84</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</logger>
<level>WARNING</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</class>
<method>executeAllActionsFound</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Fatal configuration action failed:
com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine. 
ConfigAction-/app/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/postinstall/actions 
 /CallPostinst.ant </message>
 </record>
 <record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877014</millis>
<sequence>85</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</logger>
<level>SEVERE</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</class>
<method>launch</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>ConfigManager action execution failed on a fatal action</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2017-04-11T11:37:57</date>
<millis>1491890877015</millis>
<sequence>86</sequence>
<logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</logger>
<level>INFO</level>
<class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.ConfigManager</class>
<method>launch</method>
<thread>0</thread>
<message>Returning with return code: INSTCONFFAILED</message>
</record>
</log>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is "The ServerName property must be non-empty".

If you can install from a web-based repository, I believe this was fixed in 8.5.5.10 under PI57657.

IBM HTTP Server V8 and later uses IBM Installation Manager which allows you to install directly to a fixpack, such as 8.5.5.11.  But if you use the original release media, you'll be installing 8.5.5.0 or 8.5.0.0 which may have weird initial install problems.

Setting $HOSTNAME in the native environment before launching the installation may also workaround the issue.

Finally, you could recover by running the IHS posinstallation program manually:

```
cd $IHSROOT
bin/postinst -t install -i $PWD
```

Comment: Thanks Covener. Fixed this issue by setting the Hostname in the native environment and Reinstalling the IHS.